# How do you call functions of objects which were created within an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototypejs, dynamic-typing

In the below code, the TypeError "database[(0 , 0)].returnVal is not a function" is spat back:

```
let database = [
    [
        new DatabaseItem("00", [1, 2, 3, 4], "abcd", ["haiku", "test"]),
        new DatabaseItem("01", [], "", [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    ],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
];
console.log("01 ID: " + database[0,0].returnVal());
```

but the code below is fine:

```
validityTest = new DatabaseItem("00", [1, 2, 3, 4], "abcd", ["haiku", "test"]);
console.log("test ID: " + validityTest.returnVal());
```

Is there a way to rectify this outside of just declaring all of my variables outside the array (which would make the purpose of the array minimal). I need to be able to make calls to the functions of objects within the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> database[0,0]

This isn't the right syntax for accessing a multidimensional array in javascript. This code is using the confusing [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and means: "evaluate the left 0 and ignore it, then evaluate the right 0 and use it as the index of database". In other words, it ends up being no different than doing `database[0]`.

Instead do:

```
database[0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell it's been a while since I coded?